# Survey Monkey- Custom Values via API v3

Tags: api, surveymonkey, alteryx

I am currently unable to figure out how to obtain several custom fields via the API.  The Excel extracts provide the columns I need, but I cannot find a v3 GET or POST protocol to obtain the desired fields.

From:
api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/[survey_id]/details

I see the desired fields:

1. custom_variables.a = [Variable a Column Name]
2. custom_variables.b = [Variable b Column Name]

With the following:  api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/[survey_id]/responses/bulk?page=[#]&per_page=[#]

1. data.0.custom_value = blank
2. data.0.recipient_id = blank

**10/6/16 Update: Change Custom Variables Plan Requirement**

Description of Changes: Make survey custom variables accessible to Gold plan and above.

Endpoints Affected: /surveys, /surveys/{id}, **/surveys/{id}/responses/bulk**, /collectors/{id}/responses/bulk, /surveys/{id}/responses/{id}, /collectors/{id}/responses/{id}, /surveys/{id}/responses/{id}/details, /collectors/{id}/responses/{id}/details

I hit my API call limit and have not been able to run the /collectors/{id}/responses yet.  I thought it best to ask now and get the right answer (so I can finish off this project and hit my deadline when my "counter" gets reset).  As information I am using Alteryx to make the calls, and once I get this piece completed will be posting the Workflow on the Alteryx site (to give a little back to the community).

Thank you in advance for your help!

-Drew

Answer (score 2):

So those are two different kinds of "custom values".

There are [Custom Variables](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) which are basically URL parameters that will be accepted and stored with the survey response. These only work for non-email based collectors, particularly for a Weblink collector. The custom variables are also stored on the Survey, so when you [fetch](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id) with

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>
```

You'll get a response like

```
{
  "title": "My Survey",
  "custom_variables": {
    "name1": "label1",
    "name2": "label2"
    ...

  },
  ...
}
```

Then when you [fetch survey responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-id), assuming they were filled in, you would get a response back like this:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<response_id>
{
  "id": "<response_id>",
  "response_status": "completed",
  "custom_variables": {
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2"
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

With regards to [Custom Values](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Custom-Data), these are custom data stored on a Contact resource in your address book used to create a recipient on an Email collector (not the Survey).

So when you [create a new recipient](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-messages-id-recipients) on an email collector, you can set `custom_fields` which are stored on the contact as well as the recipient. When you fetch that recipient, it'll look something like this:

```
GET /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/recipients/<recipient_id>
{
    "id": "<recipient_id>",
    "email": "<email>",
    "first_name": "<first_name>",
    "last_name": "<last_name>",
    "custom_fields": {
      "1": "field1",
      "2": "field2",
      "3": "field3",
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then when that specific recipient answers the survey and you fetch the response, you will get the contact information in the response metadata like:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/<response_id>
{
  "id": "<response_id>",
  "response_status": "completed",
  "metadata": {
    "contact": {
        {
          "id": "<response_id>",
          "response_status": "completed",
          "metadata": {
            "contact": {
                "first_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "<first_name>"
                },
                "last_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "<last_name>"
                },
                "name1": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "value1"
                },
                "name2": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "value2"
                },
                "name3": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "value": "value3"
                }
            },
            ...
          },
          ...
        }
        ...
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that metadata will only have the first name, last name, and email in the [bulk responses endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk). This is a current limitation in bulk responses.

Hope that helps clarify the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the super informative post. I know this was two years ago but I very much appreciate it -- which SurveyMonkey wrote their documentation as clearly as this :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the below url

> https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/{SURVEY_ID}/responses/bulk,

in response you get the custom variables ,

```
{
  "per_page": 50,
  "total": 6,
  "data": [
    {
      "total_time": 108,
      "href":"https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/119486428/responses/6287196301",
      "custom_variables": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
}
```

I am using web collector . and adding custom variables as url parameter.